# Initialize a bare repository but when I try to push I get does not appear to be a git reposity error

Tags: git, ubuntu

I initialized a bare repository on a mnt to a local sever using sudo git --bare init.
Then I used sudo git remot add cr2 mnt/"the path to the server".
I get a cr2 already exists, because I already created cr2.
So I use sudo git push cr2.  I get an error saying the path is not a git repository and remote end hung up.  First time I am using git with out git hub and I am unsure what I am doing wrong.  I initialized the git repository but then I get an error saying it is not a git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cd into the directory just created and try again.  Common Error.

Comment: That worked but now I am getting an up-to-date message when I try to push to cr2.  I made changes to my workspace, checked the status, then commit -all.  But when I push into cr2 I am still getting Everything up to date.  Did I forget a command?

Comment: Thanks thought, cd back into directory did help

Comment: did you add before the commit ?